# Removing checkbox frames in Acrobat?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I've got a PDF with checkboxes that the user can interact with however I cannot find a way to hide the checkbox frames for when the client views the document later:
[image]

Is there a way to hide the boxes' "frames"? Adjust some property? "Flatten" / convert the PDF to some other format? Cover the frame with a layer?

Another possibility is to align the frame with the box design to hide it but show the checkbox overflow for a fix font size? This would give the same large checkbox glyph within a small checkbox frame.

Thoughts?

Comment: Found the answer by changing "Line Style" from "Inset" to "Solid". Even if "No Color" is selected as the border and fill color, the "Line Style" value still affects appearance.

Comment: Mark, make this an answer and select it as the correct answer when you can. ( I believe there is something like 8h waiting period before you can answer your own question. ) It's better for the site if the question has a correct answer and you get some rep for figuring it out yourself.